# How to use Criteria with Projections and Order?

Tags: java, hibernate

```
Criteria criteria = sessionProvider.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Foo.class);
criteria.createAlias("game", "game");
if (from != null) criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("game.created", from.toDate()));
if (to != null) criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("game.created", to.toDate()));
criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("game")));
            criteria.addOrder(Order.desc(("game.created")));
            criteria.setMaxResults(100);
            games = criteria.list();
```

I use the code above inorder to fetch the Games. The entity **Foo** has a feild called **game**. I need to fetch the games referrerd though **Foo**. But when i run the code above i get the following error.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
  Position: 246
```

How can i add Projections and Order correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error in logic, you tried make smth like this:

```
Select Distinct game From Foo Order By created
```

Its logically wrong, server cannot order result by "created", because only "game" column present, and sort by "created" is not possible.

Comment: But the game is the column which has created.

Comment: You can order by "game" column, it present in result column list. Column  "created" is not available in result column list, and you cannot sort by this column.

Comment: Thankx. Now i got the point. The problem is when I select "distinct" it does not have unique single value of create. So I think only way for me is to query and sort manually

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and I used

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

instead of

```
Projections.distinct
```

It worked for me.